# Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_error()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just try to use codeigniter, and when I use 'validation_error();' it's always show 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_error()' on my browser.
This is my view code,

```
<?php

echo form_open('main/login_validation');

echo validation_error();

echo "<p>Email: ";
echo form_input('email');
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>Password: ";
echo form_password('password');
echo "</p>";

echo "<p>";
echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login');
echo "</p>";

echo form_close();

?>
```

This is the controller,

```
public function login_validation(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        redirect('main/members');
    } else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

and one of my autoload,

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

Please help :(

Comment: Error message is clear, where you defined `validation_error` function?

Comment: Try to fix your typo on `validation_errors()` , missing `s` i guess? see more here http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: @panther on my view code.

Comment: @BeingSunny oh my god, how stupid I am >.< Thank you, it fixed :D